# PHP include variable to filecount

Tags: php

```
$filecount = count(glob("images/profile/" . $db->getUserID($_SESSION['username']) . "*.png"));
```

The folder should now be

images/profile/1

```
$db->getUserID($_SESSION['username']);
```

returns a 1 so it seems like I have problems to include the variable into the file path.
and it exists and there is a picture inside called avatar.png. So filecount should be 1. I have a

```
if($filecount == 1)
{
    echo "Test"
}
else
{
    echo "Test2"
}
```

But it always echos Test2 and not Test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is looking for files like this:

```
images/profile/1something.png
```

You need another `/` before the `*`.

Comment: Sometimes it's so easy and you're just blind...

Thank you very much!